# How deal with flatten operator when we use conditional

Tags: apache-pig

I want to use `flatten` operation in conditional operation :

```
((FLATTEN(LIMIT_CEP.CD_AXE_MCH) == 'PME') ? 'E':'F')        AS CD_AXE_MCH_GCP,
```

Because `LIMIT_CEP.CD_AXE_MCH` is given like :

```
 {(COMM)}
 {(ARTI)}
```

But the problem here that the program return this error message

> Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'FLATTEN'

**EDIT :**

I tried also something like :

```
FLATTEN((LIMIT_CEP.CD_AXE_MCH=='PME') ? ('E') : ('P'))   AS CD_AXE_MCH_GCP,
```

But I got this error :

> mismatched input '?' expecting RIGHT_PAREN

How can I resolve it please ?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to do flatten without including conditional in first time :

```
EPSE_ENR_GCP = FOREACH (GROUP EPSE_ENR BY IDT_GCP) {

   ORDER_GROUP = ORDER EPSE_ENR BY IDC_PSE_PCL DESC, DA_PRM_CTR_ORDER DESC, IDT_ETT_PSE DESC;
   LIMIT_CEP = LIMIT ORDER_GROUP 1;

   GENERATE

    group                                          AS IDT_GCP,
    FLATTEN(LIMIT_CEP.CD_FRM_JUR)                  AS CD_FRM_JUR,
    FLATTEN(LIMIT_CEP.DA_CRE_EPS)                  AS DA_CRE_EPS,
    FLATTEN(LIMIT_CEP.NO_SIREN)                    AS NO_SIREN,
    FLATTEN(LIMIT_CEP.CD_POST)                     AS CD_POST,
    FLATTEN(LIMIT_CEP.CD_OSCE_PAYS_FIS)            AS CD_OSCE_PAYS_FIS,
    FLATTEN(LIMIT_CEP.CD_NAF)                      AS CD_NAF,
    FLATTEN(LIMIT_CEP.CD_NACE)                     AS CD_NACE,
    FLATTEN(LIMIT_CEP.CD_AXE_MCH)                  AS CD_AXE_MCH,
    FLATTEN(LIMIT_CEP.CD_AXE_SNIV_MCH)             AS CD_AXE_SNIV_MCH;

};
```

Then, in second time do conditional without any problem :

```
EPSE_ENR_GCP1 = FOREACH EPSE_ENR_GCP GENERATE

IDT_GCP AS IDT_GCP,
CD_FRM_JUR AS CD_FRM_JUR,
DA_CRE_EPS AS DA_CRE_EPS,
NO_SIREN AS NO_SIREN,
CD_POST AS CD_POST,
CD_OSCE_PAYS_FIS AS CD_OSCE_PAYS_FIS,
CD_NAF AS CD_NAF,
CD_NACE AS CD_NACE,
(CD_AXE_MCH IN ('PLIB','ATPE','COMM') ? 'P':
   (CD_AXE_MCH == 'PME'  ? 'E':
   (CD_AXE_MCH == 'AGRI' ? 'A':
   (CD_AXE_MCH == 'OBNL' ? 'O':
   (CD_AXE_MCH == 'COLL' ? 'C':
   (CD_AXE_MCH == 'EFIN' ? 'B':'X'))))))         AS CD_AXE_MCH_GCP,
CD_AXE_SNIV_MCH AS CD_AXE_SNIV_MCH;
```